# In the map named "The Puzzling," what is the solution to the room with two blocks containing 9 grass and water square combinations?

Tags: starcraft

This map is for Starcraft and it's expansion Brood War. There used to be a ton of walk-throughs for this map, The Puzzling, and it's sequel, The Puzzling 2. The idea is a team of 3 must solve each puzzle in order to reach the end. "Everything has a purpose" is the maps motto, as every peculiar design in the map is meant as a hint to solve some part of some puzzle. This particular room (picture taken from [team liquid](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=73745)'s website) has stumped me. However I cannot find a single walk-through any more using google. About 7 years ago, there were a good number of them. However, they have all seemed to have disappeared. What is the solution to this room?

I assume that the 3 discolored squares towards the top of the room are for the three players to interact with while the two 3 by 3 squares provide a hint as to what to do next.

[image: God forsaken puzzle]

There is a hint given on the teamliquid forums that may seem to indicate a solution, however, as I commented, that isn't a solution. If you look at the minimap, the first room is the top left corner room. The 2nd room is the one beneath that. There is a hidden door that's not readily visible to people not actively looking for it. That door leads to the part of a room where one of the three gems you have to retrieve is located. Solving the puzzle in that part makes it so that you can retrieve the gem later. That's what that hint means.

Next, it's difficult to get a team of 3 players to do these puzzles correctly without "rage quitting." As soon as one person quits the game is over, so I will not be able to guess and check suggestions on this map, as it even takes some time to get to the location in question (starting from scratch each time).

---

**Edit** I found [here](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=73745&currentpage=3) that there is a way to glitch the map so that one of the triggers wont work. However, I am unsure as to whether that refers to this room or not. This description of the glitch doesn't seem to correspond to this room.

I am also working on a theory that the grass spots in each of the squares corresponds to a room on the mini-map, and in those room there is an addition hint. But I can't verify that without playing the map which is quite difficult. It would explain the hint referring to the secret door, as those rooms are necessary given my theory.

Comment: While I don't have the solution. I'll see what I turn up, but what have you tried to do to solve this room?

Comment: Also, on the TeamLiquid website, there are spoilers. The one below this image says, "SECRET ENTRANCE, ROOM #2, RIGHT SIDE" which leads me to believe you can pass through the side of the second room or something and that the puzzle in there is where you actually need to be.

Comment: @skovacs1 if you look at the minimap, the first room is the top left corner room. The 2nd room is the one beneath that. There is a hidden door that's not readily visible to people not actively looking for it. If you trace the rooms from that room on right, you see it leads to the room we're having problems with. That's what that hint means.

Comment: Looks like a burrow stacking puzzle to me.

Comment: @decency lings can't borrow, the puzzling isn't that kind of map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after many failed attempts and hours of gaming, I found a team who found a solution. The solution is indeed OUTSIDE this room. The hints given in those 3 by 3 squares of grass and water are for another room.

There are two switches located later in the game which deactivate those flag barriers. However, the problem we had getting to those said rooms involved the the 3 gems we had to collect.

Placing a gem isn't enough to activate it. Each person must stand on the spot where the gem matching their colour is. Doing so opens up a new path to more rooms. It is the path opened by the activated green gem that contains the switches we need.

However, before reaching the switches, we needed to solve another puzzle. That puzzle used the hints given to us by the room mentioned in this question.

*I'll try to add pictures from the web to enhance answer later*